# How can I remove all non-word characters except the newline?

Tags: perl, text, text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
my line - some words & text
oh lóok i've got some characters
```

I want to 'normalize' it and remove all the non-word characters. I want to end up with something like this:

```
mylinesomewordstext
ohlóokivegotsomecharacters
```

I'm using Linux on the command line at the moment, and I'm hoping there's some one-liner I can use.

I tried this:

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/\W//'
```

But that removed all the newlines and put everything one line. Is there someway I can tell Perl to not include newlines in the `\W`? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This removes characters that don't match `\w` or `\n`:

```
cat file | perl -C -pe 's/[^\w\n]//g'
```

Comment: This drops the accented o in the original text.

Comment: You'll have to add a flag to the command to get it Unicode aware -C should do it.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Comment: You don't need the cat either: perl -C -pe 's/[^\w\n]//g' file

Answer (score 4):

@sth's solution uses Perl, which is (at least on my system) not Unicode compatible, thus it loses the accented o character.

On the other hand, `sed` *is* Unicode compatible (according to [the lists on this page](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Spring_2003/ling538/Lecnotes/UnixTools.html)), and gives a correct result:

```
$ sed 's/\W//g' a.txt
mylinesomewordstext
ohlóokivegotsomecharacters
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, I'd just add the -l switch, which re-adds the newline by appending it to the end of every print():

```
 perl -ple 's/\W//g' file
```

Notice that you don't need the `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous response isn't echoing the "ó" character. At least in my case.

```
sed 's/\W//g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practices for shell scripting dictate that you should use the tr program for replacing single characters instead of sed, because it's faster and more efficient. Obviously use sed if replacing longer strings.

> tr -d '[:blank:][:punct:]' < file

When run with time I get:

> real    0m0.003s 
>   user    0m0.000s 
>   sys     0m0.004s

When I run the sed answer (sed -e 's/\W//g' file) with time I get:

> real    0m0.003s 
>   user    0m0.004s 
>   sys     0m0.004s

While not a "huge" difference, you'll notice the difference when running against larger data sets. Also please notice how I didn't pipe cat's output into  tr, instead using I/O redirection (one less process to spawn).